# Checking the status of a process generated by os.system

Tags: python, process

I created a process using os.system. I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953119/python-waiting-for-external-launched-process-finish) that, normally, os.system should wait for it be completed, but I'm not sure it's the case in my code (I am calling an R script). How can I check whether the process is complete with os.sytem (I'd like to use os.system and not subprocess preferably)

Comment: Why don't you want to use subprocess?

Comment: cause I wrote a bunch of os.system and would like to avoid rewriting all my code but if there is no way to do that with os.system then I will use subprocess

Comment: I have some bad news for you, I don't believe there's any way to do what you want with ```os.system()```.  Generally replacing should be as simple as replacing all your ```os.system()``` calls with ```subprocess.call()``` calls which you can do with find and replace function

Comment: There's even a section of [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) devoted to this

Comment: os.system doc "The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function"

Comment: That should be a pretty good hint on what to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want status code

```
ret = os.system('ls -l')
print ret
```