# Kill process on a given port prior to running a flask app

Tags: python, flask

I want to kill anything on a given port (i.e. 5000) prior to launching a flask application. Here is what I have so far:

In app.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    os.system('./kill.sh')

    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

In kill.sh:

```
lsof -ti:5000 | xargs kill -9
```

If I run kill.sh in terminal everything gets killed on port 5000. So I know that works. However when I run `app.py` flask starts but THEN gets killed by `kill.sh`. So it seems that `os.system` is not waiting to finish before executing `app.run`. How can I get it to wait?

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953119/python-waiting-for-external-launched-process-finish

Comment: I could not reproduce this problem, I set my `host` and `port` both in `app.run`

Comment: I should specify that I am running in a virtualenv on Mac.