# Python's os.system within a for loop: how to wait for a command to finish before re-starting the loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.system, gnome-terminal

I am new in using os.system (in Python 3) and am trying to execute a program that I would normally run in a Linux terminal. I need to iterate a few times and am using something like the following loop:

```
for item in item_list:
    os.system("gnome-terminal -- program_execute "+item)
```

The problem is that this loop simutaneously opens `n` terminal windows (the length of my `item_list` is `n`) and executes all of them at the same time. My question is:

How could I run the loop `len(item_list)` times with the next run starting only after the current one finishes?

I can't use `sleep()` because the running time varies from item to item and I would like to optimize the process.

EDIT: I've tried using .communicate() and .wait() without success. I would like os.system (or os.subprocess) to understand that the gnome-terminal is still running, only passing by the next element in the loop after gnome-terminal from previous loop has closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python popen command. Wait until the command is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837214/python-popen-command-wait-until-the-command-is-finished)

Comment: this was already asked:
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953119/python-waiting-for-external-launched-process-finish">https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953119/python-waiting-for-external-launched-process-finish</a>

Comment: @mkrieger1, it actually does not. Even when I use .communicate() or .wait() the problem persists.

Comment: @damian863m, error 404.

Comment: How exactly did you use the `subprocess` module? Can you please update the question with a [mre]?

Comment: @mkrieger1, I managed to fix it passing a --disable-factory after calling the terminal. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used subprocess with the code below and it worked, i.e. the software runs once and finishes completely before going to the next loop.

```
for item in item_list:
    subprocess.call(["gnome-terminal","--disable-factory","--","my_command"])
```